# Concat() in mysql query and full text

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search, mysql-error-1064, concatenation

The syntax is killing me! the next query is having problems:

```
$cadbusca="SELECT * , MATCH (nombre, apellido, email, about, place, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido)) AGAINST ('$busqueda') AS Score FROM user WHERE MATCH (nombre, apellido, email, about, place, CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido)) AGAINST ('$busqueda') ORDER BY Score DESC";
```

Error:

> Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'(nombre,' ',apellido)) AGAINST ('dan stern') AS Score FROM user WHERE MATCH (nom'` at line 1.

*"dan stern"* are the words searched...

Comment: I really cant tell what up, but i think it's in the way u use the MATCH and AGAINST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a fulltext search using `MATCH/AGAINST`, you must have a full-text index on the fields you want to do the search on.  See [match/against doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match).

Having said that, you're trying to include a dynamic entity, `CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido)`, in your `MATCH`, which is not allowed -- you can't have an index on a dynamic field like that.

From the [Full-Text Restrictions doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

> The MATCH() column list must match
>   exactly the column list in some
>   FULLTEXT index definition for the
>   table, unless this MATCH() is IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE. Boolean-mode searches
>   can be done on nonindexed columns,
>   although they are likely to be slow.

Comment: therefore the only way to concatenate both colums is to make a boolean modea search?

Comment: No -- you apparently can't even do it then. Justin's suggestion of creating a column which is the concatenation you want is a good way to go if you can. Alternatively, have you considered just using the LIKE operator with wildcards? -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: thats what i finally did.... however results on so many likes are slower. Thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a column which is like the concat command you want and index against it.  (As noted by Riedsio).  Also, if you have the match in your where clause you don't need to do an 'ORDER BY' since it automatically sorts it for you.

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Getting-Started-With-MySQLs-Full-Text-Search-Capabilities/2/

Comment: That's impossible to do in select list. Only after FROM.